# CircleCI Exit Code 137 after upgrading Docker-Compose Container of MySQL from 5.7 to 8.0.2

Tags: mysql, django, docker-compose, circleci

Good day, everyone. Hope you're doing well. I've been stuck with this for quite a while now. I'm not really sure what can I do to Debug, because I'm a newbie in CircleCI. What I've done is that I've narrowed down an `Exit Code 137` from CircleCI to a change in the version of MySQL container in Docker Compose.

That error is usually related to OOM, but I've already bumped up the memory of CircleCI to 8GB with `resource_class: large` and the error keeps happening. Let me be clear this is NOT happening locally. All my containers run and work fine.

Here are my Docker-compose and CircleCI config files.
First, `docker-compose.test.yml`

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      target: dev
    command: bash -c 'python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:7777'
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    env_file:
      # stuff that don't matter...

  mysql:
    image: "mysql:8.0.2"
    # image: "mysql:5.7" # Upgrade from 5.7 to 8.0.2
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - proj-mysql:/var/lib/mysql-8.0.2
      # - proj-mysql:/var/lib/mysql # Upgrade from 5.7 to 8.0.2
    expose:
      - "3306"
    networks:
      - # More stuff that doesn't matter

volumes:
     proj-mysql-8.0.2:
     # proj-mysql <- Old 5.7
```

And `config.yml`:

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  python: circleci/python@0.2.1
  eb: circleci/aws-elastic-beanstalk@1.0.0

commands:
  setup-build-environment:
    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker:
          docker_layer_caching: true
      - run: pip install invoke flake8 boto3
      - run: touch .env

jobs:
  build-and-test:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/python:3.9.1
    resource_class: medium+
    steps:
      - setup-build-environment
      - run: inv local.test-all
# Follows some stuff that doesn't matter
```

As soon as I revert back top 5.7 all of this works fine, I get the green check in CircleCI. Has anyone encountered this issue before? Is there any way to track the issue more thoroughly?